# Updating deeply embedded documents with MongoDB 2.6.12

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using MongoDB 2.6.12 and need to update deeply embedded docs. I know that I cannot use the latest solution at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831, so I need to find the index of each doc and subdoc. I have done this and can update a single document using robomongo (yes, I still use this), like so:

```
db.getCollection('Ps').update({'dT.name': 'something', pid: 220 }, { '$set': { 'dT.0.ts.0.th': 90}})
```

However, when I run the following in my node script, I see the mongoose queries in the terminal, but nothing changes in the db:

```
let main = async function() {
let ps = [];
try {
    ps = await data.app.Ps.find({"dT.ts.th":{"$lte":1}}).exec();
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}

try {
    for (let p of ps) {
        p.dT.forEach(async function(dT, index) {
            dT.ts.forEach(async function(type, i) {
                let newValue = type.th * 100;
                await data.app.db.collection("Ps").update(
                    {pid: p.pid, "dT.name": dT.name},
                    {$set: {["dT." + index +".ts." + i + ".th"]: newValue}}
                ).exec();
            });
        });
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
};

main()
.then(() => process.exit())
.catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

This in example of the query I see being executed when my script runs:

```
Mongoose: ps.update({ 'dT.name': 'activity', progId: 220 }, { '$set': { 'dT.1.ts.0.th': 90, updatedAt: new Date("Thu, 19 Jul 2018 16:00:50 GMT"), createdAt: new Date("Thu, 19 Jul 2018 16:00:50 GMT") } }, { overwrite: true })
```

Does anyone have any ideas why a single query works in robomongo and not dynamically in a node script?

**UPDATE**

I changed the following code in my snippet above:

```
await data.app.db.collection("Ps").update(
    {pid: p.pid, "dT.name": dT.name},
    {$set: {["dT." + index +".ts." + i + ".th"]: newValue}}
).exec();
```

To:

```
console.log("Before: " + p.dT[index].ts[i].th);
p.dT[index].ts[i].set("th", newValue);
console.log("After: " + p.dT[index].ts[i].th);
p.save(function (error, result) {
   console.log("here");
});
```

My console messages show that the program attribute is being changed, but I don't see any mongoose queries in the terminal. I believe this should work per the document at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html. It is not, so what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had to change how I was doing the document `update`. I was passing the query condition into the `update()` as the first parameter, which is where the update doc should go. This resulted in mongoose interpreting your my update doc as the options parameter which resulted in no changes to those paths.

I also had to change how I was building the key of the item to be changed in the doc, as shown below, using indices selectors:

```
for (let p of ps) {
        let update = { $set: { } };
        p.dT.forEach(async function(dT, index1) {
            dT.types.forEach(async function(type, index2) {
                update.$set[`dT.${index1}.types.${index2}.th`] = type.th * 100;
            });
        });
        await program.update(update);
    }
```

I hope this helps anyone who finds this node solution. I got feedback from people at https://gitter.im/Automattic/mongoose, so thanks to them there.